# Converting cron expression from one timezone to UTC in java

Tags: java, cron

Is there any java library/API which can modify cron expression from one timezone to UTC?

For example:

I need something like this:

```
newCronExpression = convert (oneCronExpression, fromTimezone, "UTC")
```

Let me give you one example:

My local timezone is IST i.e. `GMT+5.30`.

Current local time is: `11:20 AM`.

I want a job to run in 45 min of every hour.

So, my cron expression: **45 * * * ***

Hence I am expecting my job to run after 25 min ( as starting time is `11:45 AM`)

but my job is running as per UTC.

Current time in UTC : `05:50 AM`

As per cron expression 45 * * * , the starting time will be 06:45 AM at GMT.

So, the job will be actually started after 55 min.

Expected : After 25 min

Actual : After 55 min

So,

> if I am converting my local cron expression 45 * * * to 15 * * * * at
>   GMT, then actual waiting period will be same as expected.
>
> The question is how will I convert my local cron expression to GMT for
>   all usecase in my java program.

If you have better approach, please do let me know.

*I can't schedule it as crontab in unix machine. This has to be handled in Java program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just used site for my application.
https://crontab.guru/#30_2,10,18_*_*_*

you can write something like : 0/45 * * * *

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crontzconvert

```
import { convert } from 'crontzconvert';

convert("0 0 8-10 * * *", "UTC", "US/Arizona");
> "0 0 1-3 * * *"
```